# Ranking two dimensions of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, worksheet-function, unpivot

I have a set of data in two dimensions, like so:

```
      A     B     C

 A    -     9     4

 B    24    -     13

 C    3     12    -
```

It represents relationships between two entities. I would like to return a list of those values ranked, such as:

```
AB:4
AC:5
BA:1
BC:2
CA:6
CB:3
```

Any thoughts on the best way to approach this?

Comment: I don't understand how you get the rankings, e.g., what makes AB be 4?

Comment: @DougGlancy AB is ranked 4, because (BA = 24) is ranked 1, then (BC = 13) ranked 2, (CB = 12) ranked 3, and (AB = 9) is ranked 4. In other words, the intersections are ranked based on their numerical value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a copy of your source matrix with, assuming layout as below,

```
=IFERROR(RANK(B2,$B$2:$D$4),"")
```

in G2 copied down and across to I4. From this 2D version of your rankings create a PivotTable with multiple consolidation ranges ("reverse pivot" - maybe <kbd>Alt</kbd>+D, P). Double click on the `Total`s intersect. If results are copied back in to source sheet as below (for convenience), add `=Q2&R2&": "&S2` in U2 (or adjust accordingly) and copy down to suit:

[image: SO18387948 example]

May be more appropriate for larger datasets!

Comment: This worked well. I actually do have quite a large data set, so this was a quick solution.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use VBA to create a flat table from your summary table. From then, it would be easy to sort the pairs based on their numerical value, using `CONCATENATE` and `RANK`.

Let's assume this is your starting table:

[image]

Here is the VBA code that would transform this pivot table to a flat table:
**(Go to *Developer* tab -> *Visual Basic* -> *Insert* -> *Module* -> Copy-paste the code here)**

Then click on **Run** (green *Play* sign)

```
 Sub ReversePivotTable()
 '   Before running this, make sure you have a summary table with column headers.
 '   The output table will have three columns.
     Dim SummaryTable As Range, OutputRange As Range
     Dim OutRow As Long
     Dim r As Long, c As Long
     On Error Resume Next
     Set SummaryTable = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
     With SummaryTable
          r = Application.Match("Totals", Columns(1), False)
         c = Application.Match("Total", Rows(1), False)
     End With
     Set SummaryTable = SummaryTable.Resize(r - 1, c - 1)
     MsgBox SummaryTable.Address
     If SummaryTable.Count = 1 Or SummaryTable.Rows.Count < 3 Then
         MsgBox "Select a cell within the summary table.", vbCritical
         Exit Sub
     End If
     SummaryTable.Select
     Set OutputRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a cell for the 3-column output", Type:=8)
 '   Convert the range
     OutRow = 2
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     OutputRange.Range("A1:C3") = Array("Column1", "Column2", "Column3")
     For r = 2 To SummaryTable.Rows.Count
         For c = 2 To SummaryTable.Columns.Count
             OutputRange.Cells(OutRow, 1) = SummaryTable.Cells(r, 1)
             OutputRange.Cells(OutRow, 2) = SummaryTable.Cells(1, c)
             OutputRange.Cells(OutRow, 3) = SummaryTable.Cells(r, c)
             OutputRange.Cells(OutRow, 3).NumberFormat = SummaryTable.Cells(r, c).NumberFormat
             OutRow = OutRow + 1
         Next c
     Next r
 End Sub
```

You will get a flat table like this:

[image]

Then, use `CONCATENATE` and `RANK` to get a column of pairs and ranks.

[image]

This would be the final result:

[image]

Comment: I know this method is a bit long, but that's all I could think of :)

Comment: This is just a sample table to demonstrate how the method would work. Please refer to the *test* table I am using.

Comment: I just entered random numbers in the table. Didn't really care about the actual content :)